# Creating table grid in React

Tags: reactjs

[image]

I have to create these boxes with variable number of intials boxes inside them with Reactjs.For 2 initials i have to create 4 square boxes of equal size and print initials inside them.Likewise for 5 initials we have to create 9 boxes and for 11 initals we have to create 16 boxes.can someone post react code for doing that?

Answer (score 0):

This mostly has to do with applying styles conditionally than actually rendering the elements.

For rendering the elements just use an `array.map()`.

What you have to do is get the amount of cards the component is getting and then based on that you can apply a specific style to each element in order to set their width.

I set up this very simple example in order to illustrate what I mean:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yfrfg8

The basic idea is to update the amount of cards with the buttons and depending on that value create a class that's applied to each element. In the sample I'm using bootstrap, because I have no idea what CSS you're using, so I went with the most popular one. Also the button handler is changing the amount of cards. I suposse that in your case this is through the component's props, but the idea is to show you how you can create the conditional logic to create and apply the styles depending on the amount.